# Bash -- how do I extract the third number

Tags: bash

In bash how do I extract the fourth element out of a comma-separated list such as

```
"text",1244,258,8,NA,17,NA,2423
```

i.e. I want the number `8`.

If it's easier, please recommend how I can use something like perl.

Comment: it is different the third number than the 4th element out of a comma-separated list. In this case they match, but what is the general idea? If we stick to the title the answer should be something like `sed -r 's/^[^0-9]+[0-9]+[^0-9]+[0-9]+[^0-9]+([0-9]+).*$/\1/' <<< '"text",1244,258,8,NA,17,NA,2423'`.

Comment: will `"text"` contain commas? If yes, you need a proper CSV parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use `cut`:

  ```
   echo '"text",1244,258,8,NA,17,NA,2423' | cut -d, -f4
   8
  ```

  `-d` is the option to set the char separator,  and `-f` to specify which field you are interested in. (you can specify a range)
- Or use `awk`:

  ```
  echo '"text",1244,258,8,NA,17,NA,2423' | awk -F, '{print $4}'
  8
  ```

Btw this is 4th field not 3rd.

Comment: It's the 4th field, but the 3rd number.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -aF, -lne 'print $F[3]' input.txt
```

If the input is really a CSV which could contain quoted commas and newlines, better use the [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most robust (will break on newlines inside double quotes), but with a CSV parser:

```
perl -MText::CSV -nE '
    BEGIN {$csv = Text::CSV->new()} 
    $csv->parse($_); 
    say +($csv->fields())[3];
' <<END

"hello,world",1244,258,8,NA,17,NA,2423
END
```

```
8
```

---

ruby comes with a CSV parser in the standard library:

```
ruby -rcsv -ne 'CSV.parse($_) {|f| puts f[3]}'
```

Comment: Is `Text::CSV` standard-library functionality?

Comment: Nope. Hafta get it from CPAN

Comment: Shame, that. +1, even so, for using a proper CSV parser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm at a loss for why folks are recommending tools external to bash itself -- *unless* correctly handling cases where the text string contains commas is important, there's no need whatsoever for perl, awk, or any other such tool, and handling this internally to bash will be much more efficient when processing only a single line.

```
IFS=, read _ _ _ target _ <<<'"text",1244,258,8,NA,17,NA,2423'
echo "$target"
```

...or, similarly:

```
IFS=, read -a items <<<'"text",1244,258,8,NA,17,NA,2423'
echo "${items[3]}" # first item is 0
```

---

Now, if you need to handle commas and quotes inside the text field, then it's time to pull out a CSV parser. Python includes one in the standard library, so this can be assured to work on all modern systems:

```
python -c 'import sys, csv; print csv.reader(sys.stdin).__iter__().next()[3]' \
  <<<'"text",1244,258,8,NA,17,NA,2423')
```